# parse through a `.hidden` file to ommit its contents from `ls`

Tags: bash, shell-script, ls

I want to have `ls` ignore (ommit from its output) any and all filenames that are listed in a `.hidden` file.

I found a bash function that appears to override `ls` to do this...

```
ls () {
  if [ -f .hidden ]; then
    declare GLOBIGNORE="$GLOBIGNORE:.*:$(tr '\n' ':' < .hidden)"
    ls "$@"
  fi
}
```

...but when I `source .bashrc` it returns

```
-bash: .bashrc: line 121: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: .bashrc: line 121: `ls () {'
```

I can't identity the syntax error myself (I've done a little bash scripting, but the `declare GLOBIGNORE` line is foreign to me).  Line 121 is just this: `ls () {` which seems fine itself.

Do you see an error in this function?

Is there another approach that could be used?

---

updates:

Deleting the `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` from `.bashrc` doesn't solve the `unexpected token` error.  As per advice, let's abandon that approach using globignore.

When @rkhff pointed out the `-I` (and `--ignore=`) I had the thought to try something like this (in a function first before placing in bashrc)

```
PARAM=''
if [ -f .hidden ]; then
  IGN=' -I '
  while read p; do
    $PARAM+=$IGN$p
    #$PARAM="${PARAM}${IGN}${p}"
  done < .hidden
fi
ls$PARAM
```

but that gives this mysteriously `/home/alec/bin/ls.sh: line 7: +=: command not found`.... why couldn't `+=` be found?  I haven't seen any other cases in my websearches where the `+=` operator results in "command not found".  The commented line with just the `=` also produces a command not found error.  Could someone say what could be causing this?

Comment: I *suspect* it's because your .bashrc already defines an alias for `ls`, which is being expanded when it tries to parse the function definition so that you end up with something like `ls --color=auto () {`

Comment: Yes you're correct inside default Kubuntu .bashrc: `if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then` includes that line you mentioned.

Comment: @steeldriver could you provide an answer that modifies the function I posted to include this `--color=auto()` bit?  Then I'll delete that alias that came with the default file.  That'd be sweet :)

Comment: oh.  but commenting-out those lines and sourcing the file again still results in the same error.

Comment: TBH I don't see how such a function can work; afaik `GLOBIGNORE` affects how the *shell* expands globs; if you call your `ls` function without a glob, `ls` will just list the contents of the current directory (no shell globbing involved) and if you call it with a glob, the shell will expand the glob before calling your `ls`

Comment: can you think of another way to achieve these results without using globignore?

Comment: I don't think you can use a file to define file names that should not be listed in the output of `ls`. As an alternative, you can use the `-I` (capital i) option, perhaps as an alias.

Comment: oh `-I` good point! But there's got to be a way to override with a function :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is likely because you have an earlier *alias* definition for `ls`. To demonstrate:

```
$ alias foo='echo foobar'
$ foo
foobar
$ foo () { echo barfoo; }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

**However**, I don't think you will be able to do what you want with `GLOBIGNORE`, since it only affects how the *shell* expands globs, and your shell will expand any glob expressions *before* your `ls` command is invoked.

At least with the GNU Coreutils implementation of `ls`, you may however be able to use the `-I` or `--ignore` switch ex.

```
hidls () 
{ 
    declare -a args;
    local pat;
    local patfile=".hidden";
    [[ -r $patfile ]] || { 
        command ls "$@";
        return
    };
    while IFS= read -r pat; do
        args+=("-I");
        args+=("$pat");
    done < "$patfile";
    command ls "${args[@]}" "$@"
}
alias ls=hidls
```

Comment: Aside from `foo () { …` Bash supports `function foo { …` syntax which does not collide with already defined alias.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ah that's good to know - thanks

Comment: This seems slightly more complicated than a `while` loop... is there a reason for using `mapfile` and `for` loop instead of a `while` loop?  Is the `|| return` supposed to work in place of an `if` statement?

Comment: If the current directory does not have a file named `.hidden` the bash errors `No such file or directory`.  Should it have some logic like `[ -f $1/.hidden ]` ?

Comment: @alec sure - it was not meant to be a *complete* solution, just to illustrate the method. Improve it as you wish.

Comment: Currently the function breaks a lot.  But when I try adding the logic I thought it would fix that it breaks more.  Do you have suggestions on how to make the function work when there's no .hidden file?

Comment: @alec please see revised version incorporating your suggestions

Comment: @alec DO NOT OMIT the `command` in `command ls`. The explanation I had given you to the the other question (which you have deleted) was correct: aliases are expanded in the body of functions when the functions are _defined_, not when they're run.

Comment: @steeldriver I updated the function to fix some broken parts... do you know how it could easily address the `-a` flag problem?  Thanks so much for the help!